# How to vertically concatenate two arrays in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to concatenate two arrays vertically in Python using the NumPy package:

```
a = array([1,2,3,4])
b = array([5,6,7,8])
```

I want something like this:

```
c = array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
```

How we can do that using the `concatenate` function? I checked these two functions but the results are the same:

```
c = concatenate((a,b),axis=0)
# or
c = concatenate((a,b),axis=1)
```

We have this in both of these functions:

```
c = array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that both `a` and `b` are 1D arrays and so there's only one axis to join them on.

Instead, you can use [`vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) (*v* for *vertical*):

```
>>> np.vstack((a,b))
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Also, `row_stack` is an alias of the `vstack` function:

```
>>> np.row_stack((a,b))
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

It's also worth noting that multiple arrays of the same length can be stacked at once. For instance, `np.vstack((a,b,x,y))` would have four rows.

Under the hood, `vstack` works by making sure that each array has at least two dimensions (using `atleast_2D`) and then calling `concatenate` to join these arrays on the first axis (`axis=0`).

Answer (score 6):

Use [`np.vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
In [4]:

import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
b = np.array([5,6,7,8])
c = np.vstack((a,b))
c
Out[4]:
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])

In [5]:

d = np.array ([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
d
​
Out[5]:
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
In [6]:

np.equal(c,d)
Out[6]:
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it's not a good solution, but it's simple way to makes your code works, just add reshape:

```
a = array([1,2,3,4])
b = array([5,6,7,8])

c = concatenate((a,b),axis=0).reshape((2,4))

print c
```

out:

```
[[1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8]]
```

In general if you have more than 2 arrays with the same length:

```
reshape((number_of_arrays, length_of_array))
```

Answer (score 3):

To use `concatenate`, you need to make `a` and `b` 2D arrays instead of 1D, as in

```
c = concatenate((atleast_2d(a), atleast_2d(b)))
```

Alternatively, you can simply do

```
c = array((a,b))
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. How we can horizontally concatenate using `array`? Is it only for vertically concatenation?

Comment: @user2991243 You can use the `axis` parameter to control which axis to concatenate, and it defaults to `0`.